# wordpress database not loading properly

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I wanted to make changes to our site. I took the file and mysql backups and completed the holidays. I wanted to go back from the transactions and it wasn't loaded properly. Unable to fetch Wordpress user list, unable to login to wp-admin

I wanted to make changes to our site. I took the file and mysql backups and completed the holidays